# Best way to optimize the following PHP code?

Tags: php, regex, optimization, str-replace

I'm kinda new in php. Can you tell me what is the best way to optimize this php code for best performance:

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wcddl_recents ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
$searchai = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
while($searchai = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
$searchai[query] = strip_tags($searchai[query]);
    $searchai_clean = str_replace(array("/","\\","'",'"',"<",">","-","+","%","@","%20","(",")",":","[","]","{","}","?","!")," ",$searchai[query]);
    $searchai_cleandvigubai = str_replace(" ","-",$searchai_clean);
    $searchai_cleandvigubaix = str_replace(array("---","--"),"-",$searchai_cleandvigubai);
    $searchai_cleandvigubai2 = strtolower($searchai_cleandvigubaix);
```

Comment: Profile.  For example, use xdebug+cachegrind to identify where time is being spent.

Comment: Protip: try finding several solutions to a problem, and write a test-script to see which one performs the best. The testing you do for yourself is likely easier to remember for the future.

Comment: OP, are you sure you are looking for optimization? perhaps you are just looking to make the code less ugly (which is not necessarily correlated to performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure to pay attention to the Rules of Optimization Club:

1. The first rule of Optimization Club is, you do not Optimize.
2. The second rule of Optimization Club is, **you do not Optimize without measuring**.
3. If your app is running faster than the underlying transport protocol, the optimization is over.
4. One factor at a time.
5. No marketroids, no marketroid schedules.
6. Testing will go on as long as it has to.
7. If this is your first night at Optimization Club, you have to write a test case.

The two big ones you need to pay attention to are #2 and #3.

First, you are optimizing without measuring.  You don't know yet which parts of that code block are taking the most amount of time.  To do that, you'll need a tool to tell you, such as xdebug.  Failing that, make calls to PHP's `microtime()` function after each statement to calculate how long each one takes to execute.

It seems that most of the answers being offered are giving you ways to speed up the string functions, but I'd bet a nickel that the amount of time spent in calling the SQL functions and returning rows dwarf the execution time of those string functions.  If, for example, the entire code runs in 1000ms, and the SQL calls take 970ms, and the string functions take 30ms, then even if you halve the speed of the string functions, you're only saving 15ms.

Assuming that the SQL calls are the bottleneck, see what you can do to speed them up.  Is the SQL query using the indexes that it should?  Is the ID column indexed?

Are you using the correct PHP functions?  Is there a `mysql_*` function that will return all the rows in the result in a single batch, rather than hitting the database 15 times?  For that matter, is the `mysqli_` or `pdo_` set of functions faster somehow?  The `mysql_` functions are officially deprecated.  (See the [big red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and read about the alternatives.)

Finally, how much faster do you need it to go?  If it takes 10 seconds to run now, how fast do you want it to run?  Is 9 seconds fast enough?  Or do you need it to run in 1?  You may not even be able to get the kinds of speedups you're looking for.

tl;dr: Find out what the slow parts are **before** you go trying to speed up the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? Less variables and effectively you can use the strtolower in the first statement alongside the strip_tags.

You are replacing several characters with a space and then the space with a dash. Might as well combine the two. Also remove the dash from the clean replacement. It gets replaced to a space and then a dash again, unless it is the Microsoft double dash, at which point you can add it back again in the example below.

```
$searchai[query] = strtolower(strip_tags($searchai[query]));
$searchai_clean  = str_replace(array("/","\\","'",'"',"<",">","+","%","@","%20","(",")",":","[","]","{","}","?","!"),"-",$searchai[query]);
$searchai_cleandvigubaix = str_replace(array("---","--"),"-",$searchai_clean);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't optimise it; profile it.

Use a profiler tool such as [XDebug](http://xdebug.org) to find out which parts of the code take the most time to run. Once you know which parts of the code take the most time, you can concentrate on those areas.

A small amount of work to speed up those specific areas of code will have a far greater effect than months of tinkering around the edges.

In fact, unless you're working on a site with massive traffic and need to save every single possible byte of bandwidth, all that tinkering around the edges that people refer to as "optimisation" will likely have virtually zero discernible effect.

In short: Find out what's slow; fix that. Don't bother with the rest.